# PDF Metadata and Sharepoint Document Library Metadata

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Assuming I have Document Properties Descriptions in Adobe 11 filled out is there a way I could convert that data to metadata for SharePoint in a Document Library.

In the document library I created a column for Title, Author, Subject, Keywords,

It did not import them though.

Answer (score 1):

i believe you will have to write a custom event receiver to read those pdf properties and update the item properties.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into event receivers.... another option I was thinking was putting all the metadata in the file name then grabbing it from there. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Yeah if you add all the properties in name like n:Name#T:title now when you have uploaded it you can add simple js on edit properties form parse the name and update other feild.

Comment: Does this involve document template?

Comment: Or is this form validation settings?

Comment: Nope,  you need to edit the form via sharepoint designer.  Go to your list and it should the edit form.